# Putting methods that handle HashMap of all instances of a class in a separate class

Tags: java, class, static, static-methods

I have a class that creates index cards, and within it, I have an instance variable that is a static `HashMap` that stores all the instances created.

I have been thinking a lot about it and I thought that the methods that handle the opperations over that HashMap should go in a different class, because those methods don't opperate directly over any index card, they opperate over the list of index cards.

This way, I would have an `IndexCard` class, and an `ListAdministrator` class. And both classes would handle different functions.

The problem is that this new class (`ListAdministrator`) would only have static methods, because there is only one list and there is no reason to create any new list of index cards, I only need one.

Should I move those methods to another class or should I keep it like this? Is that a good practice?

This is the code:

```
class IndexCard {
    public static HashMap <String, IndexCard> list = new HashMap <> ();
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String phone;
    public String email;
    public LocalDate dateRegister;

    IndexCard(String name, String dni, String address, String phone, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        dateRegister = LocalDate.now();
        if (Utils.validarDni(dni) && !list.containsKey(dni)) {
            list.put(dni, this);
        } else {
            throw new InvalidParameterException ("Error when entering the data or the DNI has already been previously registered");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the data of the selected card.
     */
    public void update() throws IllegalAccessException {
        String key = getKeyWithObject(this);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getFields();
        for (Field field: fields) {
            String nameField = Utils.splitCamelCase(field.getName());
            if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) && (field.getType()).equals(String.class)) {
                System.out.println ("Enter new " + nameField);
                String value = reader.nextLine().trim();
                field.set(this, value);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        list.put(key, this);
        System.out.println("Updated data \n \n");
    }

    /**
     * Delete the selected card.
     */
    public void delete() throws IllegalAccessException {
        String key = getKeyWithObject(this);
        Field [] fields = this.getClass().getFields();
        for (Field field: fields) {
            if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
                field.set(this, null);
            }
        }
        list.remove(key);
    }

    /**
     * Displays the data of the selected card on screen.
     */
    public void print() throws IllegalAccessException {
        Field [] fields = this.getClass().getFields();
        for (Field field: fields) {
            if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
                String nameFieldConSpaces = Utils.splitCamelCase(field.getName());
                Object value = field.get(this);
                System.out.println(nameFieldConSpaces + ":" + value);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print all the entries of the desired sublist with the ID, Name and phone number.
     */
    public static <T extends IndexCard> void SubClasslist (Class <T> subClass) {
        for (HashMap.Entry <String, IndexCard> entry: list.entrySet ()) {
            String key = entry.getKey ();
            IndexCard card = entry.getValue ();
            if (card.getClass().equals(subClass)) {
                System.out.println ("ID:" + key + "| Name:" + card.name + "| Phone:" + card.phone);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the object stored in the list of cards when entering the corresponding key.
     */
    public static IndexCard GetObjetWithKey(String key) {
        try {
            return list.get(key);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println (e + ": The indicated key does not appear in the database.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the Key when entering the corresponding card.
     */
    public static String getKeyWithObject (Object obj) {
        for (HashMap.Entry <String, IndexCard> entry: list.entrySet()) {
            if (obj.equals(entry.getValue())) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("The indicated data does not appear in the database, and therefore we could not obtain the key.");
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of cards when entering the main data of the card.
     * @param data Corresponds to the identifying name of the file.
     */
    public static ArrayList <IndexCard> SearchByName (String data) {
        try {
            ArrayList <IndexCard> listCards = new ArrayList <> ();
            for (HashMap.Entry <String, IndexCard> entry: list.entrySet ()) {
                IndexCard card = entry.getValue ();
                String name = entry.getValue().name;
                if (name.toLowerCase().trim().contains(data.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                listCards.add(card);
                }
            }
            return listCards;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println (e + "The indicated data does not appear in the database, you may have entered it incorrectly.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

All those static methods are what I would put in the new class.

This is how the new class `ListAdministrator` would look. It would not even need a constructor.

```
class ListAdministrator{
    public static HashMap <String, IndexCard> list = new HashMap <> ();

    /**
     * Print all the entries of the desired sublist with the ID, Name and phone number.
     */
    public static <T extends IndexCard> void SubClasslist (Class <T> subClass) {
        for (HashMap.Entry <String, IndexCard> entry: list.entrySet ()) {
            String key = entry.getKey ();
            IndexCard card = entry.getValue ();
            if (card.getClass().equals(subClass)) {
                System.out.println ("ID:" + key + "| Name:" + card.name + "| Phone:" + card.phone);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the object stored in the list of cards when entering the corresponding key.
     */
    public static IndexCard GetObjetWithKey(String key) {
        try {
            return list.get(key);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println (e + ": The indicated key does not appear in the database.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the Key when entering the corresponding card.
     */
    public static String getKeyWithObject (Object obj) {
        for (HashMap.Entry <String, IndexCard> entry: list.entrySet()) {
            if (obj.equals(entry.getValue())) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("The indicated data does not appear in the database, and therefore we could not obtain the key.");
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of cards when entering the main data of the card.
     * @param data Corresponds to the identifying name of the file.
     */
    public static ArrayList <IndexCard> SearchByName (String data) {
        try {
            ArrayList <IndexCard> listCards = new ArrayList <> ();
            for (HashMap.Entry <String, IndexCard> entry: list.entrySet ()) {
                IndexCard card = entry.getValue ();
                String name = entry.getValue().name;
                if (name.toLowerCase().trim().contains(data.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                listCards.add(card);
                }
            }
            return listCards;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println (e + "The indicated data does not appear in the database, you may have entered it incorrectly.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would definitely keep IndexCard sperate as a DTO/POCO. If my logics are critical, would even introduce an Interface, but that might 
 be overkill in this context. The logic of your methods is something for you to validate, would be hard to comment without knowing the exact requirements and by the look of it, you are not looking for logic validation. One major thought though, how do you think your methods will handle concurrency? Multiple threads trying to add/edit the static map.

Comment: @Novice I believe it won`t be any problem with concurrency since the program is designed to not perform any simultaneous actions. But if there would be any, I would just change from HashMap to any other map that can handle concurrency like ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: @Novice why would you introduce an interface?

Comment: A personal preference, seeing how your subclasses can be of different types, I would personally prefer design by contract approach. Again it depends upon the scope of the operations and future changes that needs to be incurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the concerns of managing the IndexCards and the IndexCards themselves separate because of the Single Responsibility Principle. Furthermore the ListAdministrator should handle everything that deals with the management of the IndexCards, also deletion and creation of the managed objects.

The name ListAdministrator is somehow not meeting the point as it does not administrate lists, maybe use something like IndexCardRegistry.

To deal with concurrency you could use a ConcurrentMap as your main data storage.

Having ListAdministrator all static might come in handy if your IndexCards need access to it or other IndexCards, but this would not be the best design. Do they need to know anyway? From my understanding the IndexCards could be simple POJOs that contain only data and no logic at all.

On the other hand with an all-static ListAdministrator you will not be able to use two instances of managed objects at the same time in the future without major refactoring your code. Even if you never would expect this today a well defined object registry that can handle any object might come in handy in projects to come. Therefore I would rather use real instances for the ListAdministrator (and program against it's interface to stay flexible).

**In more detail referring to your comments:**

The idea of this approach is to keep concerns clearly separated, which will make future changes to your code feasible in case the project grows (most projects tend to do so). My understanding is that the ListAdministrator should manage your IndexCards. In a way this is the same as Object Relational Mappers work, but at the moment your database is a HashMap. If you create an interface for ListAdministrator you may even swap out the HashMap with a database without having to change its clients.

On second investigation of your code I found that IndexCards not only store the data but as well have methods to update the data. This represents another break of the Single Responsibility Principle and should be dealt with. If the ListAdministrator would provide an update method for a given IndexCard it could be used by as many different clients you can think of without changing any code behind the ListAdministrators API. Your first client would be the command-line interface you already have programmed, the next might be a web service.

With an all-static ListAdministrator you have one static Class that manages one static data set. It will always only deal with IndexCards, everything you add will end up in the same HashMap (if allowed/compatible). Every part of your application with access to the class ListAdministrator would have full access to the data. If you needed another ListAdministrator (handling create, delete, update, search) for a different type you would have to refactor everything to accomodate this or start duplicating code. Why not create an instance based solution in the first place. You would have your repository for IndexCards, and could add new repositories at will.

Maybe this is over-engineering for your use case but in keeping the responsibilities clearly separated you will find out that many extensions of your code will happen orthogonal (not affecting existing code), and this is where the fun really begins. And how do you want to practice this if not with smaller projects.

**More details about the reason of using interfaces for flexible code (in response to latest comment)**

The short answer is: always code against an interface (as stated in numerous articles and java books). But why?

A Java interface is like a contract between a class and its clients. It defines some methods, but does not implement them itself. To implement an interface you define a class with `class XYZ implements SomeInterface` and the source code of the class does whatever it finds reasonable to answer to the methods defined in the interface. You try to keep the interface small, to contain only the essential methods because the smaller the interface is, the less methods you have to take into account when changes have to be made.

A common idiom in Java would be to define a `List<T>` return type (the interface) for a method, which most likely would be an `ArrayList` (concrete class), but could be a `LinkedList` (another concrete class) as well, or anything else that implements the List interface. By just returning the List interface you prevent your client to use other methods of the otherwise returned concrete class as well which would greatly reduce your freedom to change the internal implementation of your "ListProvider". You hide the internal implementation but agree to return something that fulfills the given interface. If you want to conceed to even less obligations, you could return the interface `Iteratable` instead of `List`.

Checkout the Java API, you will find standard classes like `ArrayList` implement many interfaces. You could always use an `ArrayList` internally and return it as the smallest interface possible to do the job.

Back to your project. It would be essential to refer to the Registry (ListAdministrator) via its interface, not its concrete class. The interface would define methods like

```
interface IndexCardRegistry {

     void delete(Long id) throws IllegalAccessException;

     void update(Long id, Some data) throws IllegalAccessException;

     // ...
}
```

What it does is of no concern for the client, it just hopes everything goes right. So if a client calls the repositories update method it would rely on the repository to update the targeted IndexCard. The repository could store the data as it wants, in a `HashMap`, in a `List` or even in a database, it would not matter to the clients.

```
class IndexCardMapBasedRegistry implements IndexCardRegistry {

    private Map store = new HashMap();

    void delete(Long id) throws IllegalAccessException {
        // code to remove the IndexCard with id from the hashmap 
    }

    void update(Long id, Some data) throws IllegalAccessException {
        // code to get the IndexCard with id from 
        // the hashmap and update its contents 
    }

    // ...

}
```

Now the new iteration, at creation of your registry you swap out IndexCardMapBasedRegistry for the new

```
class IndexCardDatabaseRegistry implements IndexCardRegistry {

     private Database db;


    void delete(Long id) throws IllegalAccessException {
        // code to remove the IndexCard with id from the database 
    }

    void update(Long id, Some data) throws IllegalAccessException {
        // code to update the IndexCard with id in the database 
    }

    // ...

}
```

`IndexCardRegistry indexCards = new IndexCardMapBasedRegistry();`  becomes
`IndexCardRegistry indexCards = new IndexCardDatabaseRegistry();`

The client must not change at all, but the Registry would be able to handle an amount of IndexCards that otherwise would blow your computers memory.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, I should remove all logic from IndexCard class and only leave the instance variables. Then, create a new class (IndexCardRegistry) with no constructor and no instance variables, but with all the logic. IndexCardRegistry should manage the logic of each IndexCard and the HashMap of all the cards. 

What is the advantage of using this format instead of having all in the same class? 

.

Comment: Also, I don´t quite fully understand what are you referring to with the phrase "On the other hand with an all-static ListAdministrator you will not be able to use two instances of managed objects at the same time", I would highly appreciate if you could expand on that topic a bit more.

Thanks :)

Comment: @juan Tried to answer your questions

Comment: Thank you! I undestrood everything perfectly except "If you create an interface for ListAdministrator you may even swap out the HashMap with a database without having to change its clients".

Comment: Nope, just noticed it! thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1):

Stay with IndexCard  class and dont need to create new class ListAdministrator
In class IndexCard you have list as of type hashmap and it represent in memory data structure and you have n number of method in this class to work in this data structure so i suggest stay with single class as it will serve single responsibility.